# web api2 odatacontroller error while using $select on ef partial class calculated property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to return a projection of a larger table, but also return a calculated property that resides in a partial class of the entity framework class.

I have the following (reduced for brevity):

```
Table: Book

BookID
Title
ImageFileName
ImagePath
Price
AuthorID
CategoryID
```

This works fine with the odata controller:

```
public class BookController : ODataController
{
    private bookshelfEntities db = new bookshelfEntities();

    public BookController()
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    // GET odata/Book
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<book> GetBook()
    {
        return db.books;
    }
}
```

This query to the odata controller returns the correct JSON:

```
http://localhost:63744/odata/Book?$orderby=Title&$select=BookID%2CTitle%2CImagePath%2CImageFileName
```

However I have a partial class for Book that contains a concatenation of the ImagePath and ImageFileName, that checks whether the file exists (on server) and returns the full path, or a default book cover.

```
public string BookImagePath
        {
            get
            {
                string physicalPath = GetBookFullPath() + this.BookImage;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
                {
                    return BookPath + BookImage;
                }
                else
                {
                    return ConfigurationHelper.GetSetting("RootDir") + "/Defaults/StockBookCovers/bookcover.jpg";
                }
            }
            set
            {
                BookImagePath = value;
            }
        }
```

When I return all books:

```
http://localhost:63744/odata/Book
```

the BookImagePath is returned successfully in the JSON result:

However when I include that property in a $select:

```
http://localhost:63744/odata/Book?$orderby=Title&$select=BookID%2CTitle%2CImagePath%2CImageFileName%2CBookImagePath
```

I get the following error:

```
The specified type member 'BookImagePath' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported
```

I can guess why it's not working, it's trying to create a SELECT statement to the db, and checks to makes sure all the requested fields are part of the ef model first.

Is there a way to do this *without* either creating a view in the db, or creating a separate api method that would return all the data then do it's own filter?

**Interestingly even when you don't use a $select clause in the url, the SQL generated explicitly references all fields in the table anyway (not a SELECT *, but a SELECT, BookID, Title,.etc.)**

I would hope it could still do the data retrieval, then hydrate the ef object along with any non-db properties.  (I could understand it, if it were on a *where* part of the created linq expression, but not a select)

If, for example, the calculated property referenced a field not retrieved as part of the select then the calculated property should/could handle that or throw a different error.

**Is this just a frustrating "feature" of the odata implementation, that uses linq in the background, and it's linq that can't handle the computed property being referenced directly as part of the query?**

If so, does anyone know if there are plans to improve the implementation of Linq to allow this?

Thanks for any help/ideas.

For version reference here's the Microsoft packages in my packages.config:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.13" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```